# remove username validation from authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I am implementing Authlogic for user authentication.

I want to remove username validation so that multiple users with same username exist in the database.

how do I achieve that

any help

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of email validation:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.validate_email_field = false
end
```

In case of any username field validation:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.validate_login_field = false
end
```